# Access nested subfields in a structure by a string

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a struct like this

```
A.b.c.xx
A.b.d.xx
```

and would like to store the sub-struct in a string or anything else like this

```
s = 'b.c'
```

Now I would like to access the subfields of the struct in the following manner:

```
test = A.(s).xx
```

Is this possible and how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, do this:

```
eval(['A.' s '.xx'])
```

Answer (score 4):

The fieldnames in a struct can either be typed directly (e.g. `A.b`) or via a string variable (e.g. `name = 'b'`, `A.(name)`). However you cannot specify `name = 'b.c'`, as I guess you already figured out. You would therefore have to split the string manually, using

```
A.(s(1)).(s(3))
```

This might help for simple cases, but is not very general. To [evade `eval`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) and still have more flexibility, you can use the [`getfield`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html) function and use `strsplit` to find the different field names in the string `s`.

```
fields = strsplit(s,'.')
getfield(A,fields{:},'xx')
```

Comment: Sure, but I didn't mind using `eval` because the data structure itself is ugly. Why would @quant use `b.c` as indexing? If anyway a string is required for indexing, I would just use one field, e.g. 'b'. In this way, dynamic members can be applied: `A.(b)`.

Comment: `getfield` is just a wrapper for [dynamic field referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/), so this approach is not generic. As soon as the structure of `s` changes, so too must your `getfield` call. As much as we're loathe to use `eval`, as far as I know it's the most appropriate approach for this situation.

Comment: I added a more generic approach, which doesn't need `eval`. I try not to use `eval` for performance reasons, but also as it is a potential security risk.